# when i go to screen other and press back button then screen will not refresh

Tags: flutter

i use this fuction in back screen  go but not page refresh and not update notificatoion count

```dart
final alertsScreen = AlertsScreen(userId: loginController.currentUser.value?.id ?? '');
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => alertsScreen));
    Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    // Reload data when the user presses the back button
    await fetchNotifications;
    await markNotificationAsRead;
    await _showNotificationDetails;
    print("hello");
    Navigator.pop(context, alerts.length);
    return true;
    // Allow the back navigation
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make async method (if it is not) and and use `await` before `push` and next line call `setState` to update the UI.

```dart
yourMethod() async{
  await Navigator.push(...);

  //if you've methods needed to call 
  await fetchNotifications();// make sure call method with `()`

  setState((){});
}
```

Comment: its not working