# when i go to alert screen notification read and press back button then screen will not refresh and not update a notification

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

```
final alertsScreen = AlertsScreen(userId: loginController.currentUser.value?.id ?? '');
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => alertsScreen));
    Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    // Reload data when the user presses the back button
    await fetchNotifications;
    await markNotificationAsRead;
    await _showNotificationDetails;
    print("hello");
    Navigator.pop(context, alerts.length);
    return true;
    // Allow the back navigation
  }
```

i use this fuction in back screen go but not page refresh and not update notificatoion count

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when i go to screen other and press back button then screen will not refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77272841/when-i-go-to-screen-other-and-press-back-button-then-screen-will-not-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using **Navigator.pop()**, you have to consider using state management. State management will take care of the rebuilding of widgets that watches any changes in an object (in your case, an int notificationCount), reflecting the most updated value of the object.

*Additional Note:*
There are many reliable state management packages on offer in pub.dev. You can choose one that you are most comfortable with. I personally use riverpod.

An example for your case using riverpod.

**Add the [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) package to your *pubspec.yaml* file.**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter  
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.6
```

Create a file, e.g. *lib/tool/provider/notificationCount.dart* and create notifier provider for the object you want to keep track of, in this case is the notificationCount int.

Since it is a simple integer type object, using State Provider should be ample.

```
final notificationCountProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) {
  // initial value to return (e.g. 0)
  return 0;
});
```

to update the value on following an event (for example a button click), you can use ConsumerWidget as follow,

```
// extends ConsumerWidget instead of StatelessWidget
class FirstScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  // now we have access to WidgetRef
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // watch the notificationCount
    final notificationCount = ref.watch(notificationCountProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text(notificationCount),
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your second screen, where you put the event logic that changes the notification count,

```
class SecondScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('do something, adds the count, and go back'),
            onPressed: () async {
                 // asynchronous await for a future function to complete
                 await exampleFutureFunction();
                 // increase the count by 1
                 ref.read(notificationCount.notifier).state++;
                 // pop the second screen to return to first 
                 Navigator.pop(...);
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

When SecondScreen pop to FirstScreen, the notificationCount, will reflect the latest value.

Using state management is highly recommended as it will make your code more robust, and easier to maintain as your code base grows.

Here's a very good [resource](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-state-management-riverpod/) to learn about riverpod.

Comment: I think that looking at the current problem and advising any state management library may no be a good advice. Current problem could fixed easily without depending on any third party package. 

To understand need of any state management solution, first we need to understand 

- what is the scope of the project
- what do we want to do
- what will be the benefits of state management solutions instead of flutter core solutions or kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
You could return any value that you need from pop action.

...
await fetchNotifications;
await markNotificationAsRead;
await _showNotificationDetails;
....
Navigator.pop(context, returnValue);

-> returnValue can be anything

A map, A model, A variable type etc.

And check your returnValue after pop action ->  

final returnValue = await Navigator.push(...);

if (returnValue != null) {
   setState(() {
      // do anything that you want after pop action
   });
}
```